# How can I fix this error on OpenShift: ImportError: libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, caching, openshift

I have python 2.7 cartridge, using Django framework and I want use memcached with it. I have added Memcached Cloud cartridge to my app. And I used this guide https://redislabs.com/django-memcached to setup my project. 
To use  Django caching backend - 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache', I need to Install memcached binding called pylibmc, this bindings require libmemcached to be installed. I have installed pylibmc with corresponding path to libmemcached, but when I try to use cache in my project I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/lib/openshift/<USER_ID>/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    cache = _create_cache(alias)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/<USER_ID>/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 88, in _create_cache
    return backend_cls(location, params)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/<USER_ID>/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 182, in __init__
    import pylibmc
  File "/var/lib/openshift/<USER_ID>/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylibmc/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    import _pylibmc
ImportError: libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?
Maybe solution is something like: 
ln -s ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}libmemcached /lib/libmemcached.so.11 /usr/lib/libmemcached.so.11
But I haven't permission to do it.

Comment: try to install pylibmc with --no-use-wheel flag: 'pip install pylibmc --no-use-wheel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

We can customize dynamic linker.

If you have root privileges you can edit **/etc/ld.so.conf** file and then run

```
$ ldconfig
```

But if haven't root privileges setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable like this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}libmemcached/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: What did you edit in the ld.so.conf? Mine has: "include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf". And the ldconfig command did not fix the pylibmc import.